# Generic as parameter, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, generics

I am learning basic sort algorithms from some source in github. Now, I am trying to make a method that can be used for all sorter instance but I am facing error CS1503 which says that I can not convert int[] into T[]. The intellisense recommends me to add new method but I don't want to add it. Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test<int>(new BubbleSorter<int>(), new IntComparer());
    }

    static void test<T>(ISorter<T> sorter, IComparer<T> intComparer)
    {
        var (correctArray, testArray) = RandomHelper.GetArrays(10); //Generates random arrays
        sorter.Sort(testArray, intComparer); //This line error
        Array.Sort(correctArray);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", testArray));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", correctArray));
    }
}

public interface ISorter<T>
{
    void Sort(T[] array, IComparer<T> comparer);
}

class BubbleSorter<T> : ISorter<T>
{
    public void Sort(T[] array, IComparer<T> comparer) {//Sort}
}

internal class IntComparer : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Compare(int x, int y)
    {
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}

internal static class RandomHelper
{
    public static (int[] testArray, int[] correctArray) GetArrays(int n)
    {
        int[] testArr = new int[n];
        int[] correctArr = new int[n];

        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int t = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
            testArr[i] = t;
            correctArr[i] = t;
        }

        return (testArr, correctArr);
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve that I want to do this with one test method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test<int>(new BubbleSorter<int>(), new IntComparer());
        test<int>(new SelectionSorter<int>(), new IntComparer());
        test<int>(new MergeSorter<int>(), new IntComparer());
    }
```

Comment: `CS1503 which says that I can not convert int[] into T[]` What **exactly** does it say?

Comment: Since `RandomHelper.GetArrays(10)` isn't generic, I suspect the issue lies there. You have no guarantee that `T` will only ever be `int`, and `GetArrays` appears to return `int[]`. If this compiled, what would happen if I called `test<MyComplexObject>(sorter, comparer)`? And, on the off chance that you only want `T` to ever be `int`, you don't need to use generics at all.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using generics here?

Answer (score 2):

`test` is supposed to be able to work on any `T`, right? But `RandomHelper.GetArrays` can only return `int[]`! To make your `test` method able to test any `T`, you need to write a `GetArrays` method that can generate test cases for any `T` as well, not just for `int`.

So now you have two choices:

1. Make `test` non-generic because you only need to sort `int`s here.
2. Make `GetArrays` work on any `T`.

For option 1, you can just remove all the `<T>` and replace `T` with `int`, like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test(new BubbleSorter(), new IntComparer());
    }

    static void test(ISorter sorter, IComparer<int> intComparer)
    {
        var (correctArray, testArray) = RandomHelper.GetArrays(10);
        sorter.Sort(testArray, intComparer);
        // Array.Sort(correctArray); // you should do this in GetArrays instead! You should also pass intComparer to Array.Sort as well!
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", testArray));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", correctArray));
    }
}

public interface ISorter
{
    void Sort(int[] array, IComparer<int> comparer);
}

class BubbleSorter : ISorter
{
    public void Sort(int[] array, IComparer<int> comparer) {//Sort}
}
```

One way to do option 2 is to add a `Func<int, T>` parameter to `GetArrays` telling it how to transform an `int` to a `T`. You would also need a `IComparer<T>` parameter to sort the correct array as I mentioned above,

```
public static (T[] testArray, T[] correctArray) GetArrays<T>(int n, Func<int, T> transform, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    T[] testArr = new T[n];
    T[] correctArr = new T[n];

    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int t = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
        testArr[i] = transform(t);
        correctArr[i] = transform(t);
    }
    Array.Sort(correctArray, comparer);
    return (testArr, correctArr);
}
```

And you can call `GetArrays` like this:

```
static void test<T>(ISorter<T> sorter, IComparer<T> intComparer)
{
    var (correctArray, testArray) = RandomHelper.GetArrays(10, x => x, intComparer);
    sorter.Sort(testArray, intComparer);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", testArray));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", correctArray));
}
```